# What is a concise way to create inline elements in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I like to put all my inline elements in a single line.

```
<ul>
  <li><a>click<span>here</span><strong>!</strong></a></li>
```

Wondering if there's a better way to create inline elements in Jade than this:

```
ul
  li 
    a(href="#") click 
      span here
      strong !
```

This get's a little closer but I'm not sure how to add the span and strong tags without breaking the lines.

```
ul
  li: a(href='#') click
    span ...
```

This obviously isn't a super big problem but it's a little annoying that I can't put inline elements inline. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 128, accepted):

[Since version 1.0](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1323), jade supports inline tags:

```
#[tag(attribute='value') inner stuff]
```

In your case that would be:

```
ul
  li #[a(href="#") click  #[span here #[strong !]]]
```

Comment: This is SO much easier than the above syntax. Thanks! I've been looking for this for awhile!

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Definitely the one. Shame that Sublime's Jade lang doesn't highlight this syntax...

Comment: Really a shame, because Atom's does.

Answer (score 30):

Ran into this today myself. Found a way to do this in jade using the pipe. 
Here is my example wrapping a strong tag inside a p element.

```
p.some-class
    strong This Renders Strong                          
    |This renders normal
```

Comment: Ah, been looking for something like this for ages. Cheers.

Comment: This is the better answer? Perfect for my needs.

Comment: You won't get a space between Strong and This though:  `...Strong</strong>This...`

Answer (score 17):

I also struggled with this a while back; the only answer I found is to just use HTML.

```
ul
  li: a(href='#') click<span>here</span><strong>!</strong>
```

Comment: The `<` and `>` will become `&lt;` and `&gt;` after rendering the jade into HTML.